# Interfaces that define similar responsibilities

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say I have an interface `ICanRotateWithinLimitedRange`. There are two ways to specify the range over which an object can rotate:

1. One could specify the `StartingAngle` and `EndingAngle`.
2. One could, alternatively, specify the `StartingAngle` and `RotationRangeInDegrees`.

(Let's say that these angles are defined with respect to the zenith.)

In both cases, `StartingAngle` is necessary information, and in addition `EndingAngle` **xor** `RotationRangeInDegrees` should be specified. In my opinion, it is therefore wrong to define `ICanRotateWithinLimitedRange` as follows:

```
public interface ICanRotateWithinLimitedRange
{
    float StartingAngle { get; }
    float EndingAngle { get; }
    float RotationRangeInDegrees { get; }
}
```

There should really be two interfaces, for the two different ways in which one can specify the rotation range.

However, the name `ICanRotateWithinLimitedRange` would be suitable for both interfaces, so how do I appropriately name the interfaces to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Fairly opinion-based, isn´t it? There´s no right or whrong answer here, as no-one forces you to use some special naming-convention. You could give completely arbitrary names for your interfaces. Apart from this answers this qiestion tend to become something like `Name`, `MyName`, `AnotherName`, which all don´t fit very well to SO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think it is still possible to say whether some suggestions are objectively better or worse than others. (To give a ridiculous example, ``ILikeIceCream`` would be an obviously bad suggestion. (Of course no one is actually going to suggest that, but I am simply trying to make a point that it is not as opinion-based as you think.) Or maybe someone can point out why my abstraction is bad.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve by having two interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why this is an interface at all. It's representing the range of valid rotations, not the ability to rotate anything. Interfaces are usually best to represent capabilities rather than just data objects, IMO. It's hard to see how there could be multiple useful representations of the data represented here.

A rotation created in either form can express all three values, so I'd just write a separate class or struct with factory methods to express the two different ways of creating instances:

```
// Note: You may well want to make this a struct instead.
public sealed class RotationRange
{
    public float Start { get; }
    public float End { get; }
    public float Range => End - Start;

    private RotationRange(float start, float end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public bool IsValid(float angle) => angle <= Start && angle < End;

    public static RotationRange FromStartAndEnd(float start, float end) =>
        new Rotation(start, end);

    public static RotationRange FromStartAndRange(float start, float range) =>
        new Rotation(start, start + range);
}
```

The names may need to be changed - it's not *entirely* clear what's meant here... it's possible that `Start` and `End` should really be `MinimumAngle` and `MaximumAngle` for example, and it's odd to use `Range` for both the length of the range and the range itself. You may want to add units as well. (You have "degrees" in your question, but only for one property, whereas presumably it applies to all of them.)

Oh, you probably want a bunch of validation :)

You might have a separate interface which uses the class as a parameter or return value. For example:

```
public interface IRotatable
{
    RotationRange RotationRange { get; }
    // This must be valid according to RotationRange
    void Rotate(float angle);
}
```

That represents the actual ability to rotate.

Comment: Why methods are `static`?

Comment: @Fabio: They're factory methods. I've edited to make that clearer.

Comment: @Fabio you cannot use constructor here, because both options are represented by two floats, so only way is making constructor private and use separate static methods with meaningful names.

Comment: So idea is to use one interface with one method `(startAngle, endAngle)` and "factory" will calculate `endAngle` when `range` given

Comment: @Fabio: No, the `RotationRange` class doesn't implement any interfaces at all, although it could be *used* in an interface.

Comment: @DaisyShipton, sorry you updating answer so quickly ;).

Comment: Note that, while your answer is indeed a solution, it resigns consumers of this API to use the "start+end" methodology. If a consuming developer prefers to use the "start+angle" method, they'll have to convert their parameters before they can correctly create a `RotationRange`.

Comment: @Flater: I don't see that at all. Did you miss the `FromStartAndRange` method (and the fact that the constructor is private)? That's for creation - and consumers can ask for any of the three properties. In other words, the API is completely ambivalent as to which representation you want to use.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: My mistake. I initially interpreted those as being conversion methods for an already constructed object. Should learn to read better :)

Answer (score 0):

> There are two ways to specify the range over which an object can rotate

I am going to work under the assumption that one can **always** choose between these two methods.

---

The method that executes the rotation (`Rotate()`) should be independent of the parameters of the allowed rotation.

*Note: Of course it's related in the sense that it knows where to find the needed parameters, but the method should work agnostic of which of the two parameter sets your user has picked.*

Therefore, the rotation has a simplified signature:

```
public void Rotate(IRotationParameters parameters)
```

This enables you to develop the method body without caring about how the parameters were defined.

---

With the method body developed, the challenge then becomes defining the parameters (either way).

Since you're already using interfaces, let's extend that approach:

```
publc interface IRotationParameters
{
     float StartingAngle { get; }
     float EndingAngle { get; }
     float RotationAngle { get; }
}
```

Assuming any `IRotationParameters` will always expose all three variables, you will **always** be able to implement a rotation (however you please).

---

Let's assume we have three developers, who each prefer a particular rotation method.

- Dev A prefers the `start+angle` method.
- Dev B prefers the `start+end` method.
- Dev C, who has developed the `Rotate()` method, has an unknown preference.

**How Dev A can be satisfied:**

Using this class:

```
public class RotationParametersFromStartAndAngle : IRotationParameters
{
     public float StartingAngle { get; private set; }
     public float EndingAngle { get; private set; }
     public float RotationAngle { get; private set; }   

     public RotationParametersFromStartAndAngle(float start, float angle)
     {
         this.StartingAngle = start;
         this.RotationAngle = angle;
         this.StartingAngle = start + angle;
     } 
}
```

**How Dev B can be satisfied:**

Using this class:

```
public class RotationParametersFromStartAndEnd : IRotationParameters
{
     public float StartingAngle { get; private set; }
     public float EndingAngle { get; private set; }
     public float RotationAngle { get; private set; }   

     public RotationParametersFromStartAndEnd (float start, float end)
     {
         this.StartingAngle = start;
         this.StartingAngle = end;
         this.RotationAngle = end - start;
     } 
}
```

**How Dev C can be satisfied:**

Dev C will always be satisfied, since `IRotationParameters` facilitates both approaches. He can develop his method however he pleases (even if he's a weirdo who thinks the third "angle+end" method should be used).

---

> **Remarks**
>
> - I used two different parameter classes. You could've also used a single class with two static "constructory" methods. You wouldn't need an interface then since you're only using a single class.
> - You could have either `EndingAngle` or `RotationAngle` be a calculated property instead of calculating it in the constructor.
> - There are many variations possible here. I tried to stick with a simple and clear one that uses interfaces (which you were already working with).